# Use two different Bottom Tab navigator

Tags: react-native

I am creating a app, where I need to show Bottom Tab Navigator after login.

I know, it is easy with the help of `createBottomTabNavigator`. But there is little twist:

We have two types of Users. Say "Admin" and "Student". And we need to show different screens stack for both types of users in Bottom Tab Navigator. Both users have same number of tabs, tab icons, etc. Only the screen stack is different.

So my question is, what will be good approach to handle this case:

- Should I create two Bottom Tab Navigator using `createBottomTabNavigator`, and then add both in `createSwitchNavigator` ?
- Or I will create a "Component", and there check, if user type is "Admin", then return "First Bottom Tab Nav" otherwise return "Second" in `render` function ?

Or any other good approach, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I am going with this approach for now (and it is working fine):

**Should I create two Bottom Tab Navigator using createBottomTabNavigator, and then add both in createSwitchNavigator ?**

Here is the route stack:

Admin stack Navigator:

```
const AdminStack1 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    AdminScreen1,
  },
  {headerMode: 'none', initialRouteName: 'AdminScreen1'},
);

const AdminStack2 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    AdminScreen2,
  },
  {headerMode: 'none', initialRouteName: 'AdminScreen2'},
);
```

Student stack Navigator:

```
    const StudentStack1 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    StudentScreen1,
  },
  {headerMode: 'none', initialRouteName: 'StudentScreen1'},
);

const StudentStack2 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    StudentScreen2,
  },
  {headerMode: 'none', initialRouteName: 'StudentScreen2'},
);
```

Admin Tab navigator:

```
const AdminTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: AdminStack1,
  Calendar: AdminStack2,
},
{
// tabBarOptions
});
```

Student tab navigator:

```
const StudentTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: StudentStack1,
  Calendar: StudentStack2,
},
{
// tabBarOptions
});
```

Drawer navigator:

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Admin: {
      screen: AdminTabNavigator,
    },
    Student: {
      screen: StudentTabNavigator,
    },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: Sidebar,
    drawerWidth: 310,
    drawerType: 'front',
  },
);
```

Main switch navigator:

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Login,
    Main: DrawerNavigator,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
  },
);
```

And finally, App container:

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

And after login, I have this check:

```
if (userType === 'Admin') {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('AdminScreen1');
} else {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('StudentScreen1');
}
```

So when `AdminScreen1` starts, then it automatically starts the Admin tab navigator, as this screen only present in Admin tab navigator. Otherwise it starts the Student tab navigator.

Please suggest, if there are any other better approach.